# Which Xamarin pcl profile should I use for dependency injection and http calls

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

I'm in process of building a Xamarin app which was worked on by someone else. All the code was written in the code behind. So I took it upon myself to build it right using mvvm and dependency injection. I'm using Mvvmlight which comes with SimpleIoc. I'm using profile 111. The problem is that SimpleIoc is not resolving my registered classes it does work when I use profile 78 but 78 doesn't have HttpClient. Is there a specific profile I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Microsoft.Net.Http NuGet package for using HttpClient